# Collision Detection in Cocos2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection

I am designing a game in which I have used 40 CCSprite objects. I need to detect the collision in between them. I am able to detect the collision between 2 sprites. Now how can i check 1 objects against all the remaining objects? Is using a FOR loop will work? or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think for a first iteration you should implement the for loop and see if it's fast enough.

If it's not, I guess you could partition your game area into rectangles and distribute your objects to rectangles (an object that overlaps multiple rectangles belongs to all of them). Then when you do the collision you can check only in the rectangle where your initial object is placed. Of course this depends a lot on what you have there. If all objects move around a lot it might not be such a hot idea.

Answer (score 0):

Why dob't you use Box2D or chipmunks

For Box2D this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/606/how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone) will help.

For Cocos2D following code will help.

You need to add following lines

> shape->collision_type  = kCollisionTypeParticle;
>   cpSpaceAddCollisionHandler(space_, kCollisionTypeParticle, kCollisionTypeParticle, collisonDetect, NULL, NULL, NULL, self);

Here collisonDetect is a method we need to register as:

> cpBool collisonDetect(cpArbiter *arb, struct cpSpace *space, void *data) 
>   {
>         *layer = ( *)data;
>        [layer collisonDetect:arb];
>        return cpTrue;
>   }

Now here here you will handle rest of the code

> -(void)collisonDetect:(cpArbiter*)arb
>   {
>           NSLog(@"COLLISION DETECTED");
>   }